# Need a better approach in how to design this relation

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have a table `fluxo`, and fluxo have many `fluxo_acao`, but a entry in `fluxo_acao` can have three types, and each type have they particularities. to acomplish this, i created more three tables(`fluxo_acao_mensagem`, `fluxo_acao_pergunta` and `fluxo_acao_escolher_fila`), connected to `fluxo_acao`.

The problem is i can't select any of the three tables, from `fluxo`, because first i need to check wich type is and them i do the query.

I need a better approat in how to acomplish this relation. Even why i need create another two more. and this is the perfect time to change.

[image: fluxo]
[image: fluxo_acao]
[image: other three tables]

Comment: Please don't put things in your post other than what's needed to ask it. You could leave a comment that you cross-posted before realizing it was disallowed. Closing means answers are blocked, but you can still get votes. Please edit your posts to improve whenever you can. I think that askers can self-close immediately as a duplicate. PS Your final question is 2 questions with an OR; consider asking 1 good version of 1 of them. I voted the design issue as a duplicate. But if you research being stuck querying, it's also a faq & if you do ask, give a [mre]. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: My comments are neutral, relevant & helpful.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. wasn't the general content, but the way you said. I edited in the top of the question because i was trying to avoid someone to post any answer and a comment may will missed. i'm accepting the duplecate suggestion. I'm done with this subject.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand what exactly these types are supposed to do, but it sounds like inheritance could help you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-inheritance.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i'm checking the link. i will let you know if help me.

Comment: This link is severely outdated, and I don't see how inheritance could help here.

Comment: it's supported by the newer postgres versions too https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/tutorial-inheritance.html

Comment: i think it does help, he will have one base type `fluxo_acao`, and three types that inherit from it (`fluxo_acao_mensagem`, `fluxo_acao_pergunta`, `fluxo_acao_escolher_fila`).

Comment: More often than not, inheritance is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the columns for all three types to `fluxo_acao` and use a check constraint to ascertain that the correct columns are `NULL` or `NOT NULL` for each type. Then the join would be trivial.

For convenience, you could define views on `fluxo_acao` for each type that show only the pertinent columns.